# Protocol Delegate doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi Im trying to download a Photo from the internet using GCD. After the image is downloaded I call the delegate to let the class know that the image is downloaded.

Here is the code I use to download the image

```
-(void)getVenuePhotos:(NSString  *)venueID
{
    dispatch_queue_t  getVenuePhotos =  dispatch_queue_create ( "getVenuePhotos" ,  NULL );
    dispatch_async (getVenuePhotos, ^{

       //Download image, Lots of code not displaying
        UIImage *image  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            //This delegate doesn't get called
            [self.delegate gotVenuePhotos:image];  
        });
    });
    dispatch_release (getVenuePhotos);
}
```

Here is how I implemented my Protocol in my POIPhoto.h

```
@protocol POIPhotoProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)gotVenuePhotos:(UIImage *)image;
@end

@interface POIPhoto : NSObject

-(void)getVenuePhotos:(NSString *)venueID;

@property(nonatomic, weak) id <POIPhotoProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

And in my class I want the call back

```
@interface PoiDetailViewController : UIViewController <POIPhotoProtocol>
```

And finaly I implement the protocol method

```
-(void)gotVenuePhotos:(UIImage *)image
{
   self.venuePhoto.image = image;
}
```

The problem is that the `gotVenuePhotos` never gets called even though in my image downloader the `[self.delegate gotVenuePhotos:image];`  gets called

Comment: It may require to set delegate to `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are not setting the delegate.
In your `viewDidLoad` set the delegate like:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed that.